# How do I made a totally blank website by editing blogspot html code so that I can customize the whole website by scratch?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I want to customize the whole website of blogspot but I when I delete the whole existing code it shows a parsing error. Is there any way I can have only the parsed website which can look blank when opened so that I can edit it whole.

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to recode an existing website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:defaultwidgetversion='2' b:layoutsVersion='3'>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
    <title><data:view.title/></title>

    <b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin>

  </head>
  <body>
    <b:section id='main-section'>

    </b:section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

As the code below you will have a blank page on Blogger:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
<head>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
<b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin>
</head>
<body>
<b:section id='main-section'>
<!-- BODY CONTENTS -->
</b:section>
</body>
</html>
```

### Full Answer

A Blogger template consists of XHTML and blogger elements. To design a basic layout of the template, you will use namespaces. A namespace (xmlns) is pre-defined to use with the Blogger by Google. 3 types of namespaces are basically used as follows

- xmlns:b – ‘b’ specifies that this namespace is used to access the
  blogger elements.
- xmlns:data – It is used to specify that from where the data of the
  blog comes.
- xmlns:expr – Calculates the expression for attributes.

You will write all the code in main.xml file of Blogger.

---

**Step 1: Syntax for Basic Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
<head>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- BODY CONTENTS -->
</body>
</html>
```

**- Sections**

A blogger template is divided into sections. The basic sections are: Header, Content, Footer, Sidebar. You will use the Widget element to define the content in a section. Note that you can’t use HTML within a section. But around a section, it’s permissible to use HTML.

The correct format of section will be:

```
<b:section id=’ ‘ class=' ' maxwidgets=' ' showaddelement=' '>
<b:widget……../>
</b:section>
While the below format, will be considered Wrong:
<b:section id=' ' class=' ' maxwidgets=' ' showaddelement=' '>
<h1>Content heading</h>
<div>Content</div>
</b:section>
```

**- Section Attributes**

You need to specify following attributes in a section. id is the only required attribute while others are optional.

- id – It is the unique name of section specified in letters and
  numbers only.
- class – Consists of common classes such as ‘navbar,’  ‘main,’
  ”header,’  ‘footer, and ‘sidebar,’. If you change templates later,
  these will let you to decide whether transfer your content or not.
  You can also use other class names if you wish.
- maxwidgets – It limits the maximum number of widgets that can be
  added in a section.
- showaddelement – Consists of ‘yes’ or ‘no’ value. ‘Yes’ is the
  default. This establishes whether the Page Elements tab displays the
  ‘Add a Page Element’ link or not.
- growth – It can be ‘horizontal’ or ‘vertical’. ‘vertical’ is the
  default. This determines whether widgets are arranged side-by-side or
  stacked within a section.

**Step 2: Syntax to Add Sections**

```
<b:section id='header' class='header' maxwidgets="1" showaddelement="no">
<!-- Section contents -->
</b:section>
<b:section id="sidebar" class="sidebar" maxwidgets="" showaddelement="yes">
</b:section>
<b:section id='main' class='main' maxwidgets="1" showaddelement="no">
<!-- Section contents -->
</b:section>
<b:section id='footer' class='footer' showaddelement="no">
<!-- Section contents -->
</b:section>
```

**- Widgets**

A widget is the main part which displays real data for section. It works as a placeholder. Section only defines the layout elements. Some default widgets are available in blogger. However, you can also create your own custom widget.

**- Widget Attributes**

Widget can have many attributes. Out of which, only id and type are required and others are optional.

- id – It can have letters and numbers only. Each widget ID is unique.
  A widget’s ID can only be changed by deleting the widget or creating
  a new widget.
- type – It indicates the type of widget and can have one of the valid
  widget types listed below

1. BlogArchive
2. Blog
3. Feed
4. Header
5. HTML
6. SingleImage
7. LinkList
8. List
9. Logo
10. BlogProfile
11. Navbar
12. VideoBar
13. NewsBar

- locked – It can have a ‘yes’ or ‘no’ value. The default value is
  ‘no’. You cannot move or delete a locked widget from the Page
  Elements tab.
- title – Displays the title of the widget. If not specified, a default
  title such as ‘List1’ is used.
- pageType – It can be ‘all,’ ‘archive,’ ‘main,’ or ‘item’. ‘All’ is
  the default. A widget will display only on the designated pages.
- mobile – It can be ‘yes’, ‘no,’ or ‘default’. It tells a widget will
  display on mobile or not. Only Header, Blog, Profile, PageList,
  AdSense, Attribution will be displayed on mobile if it is set to
  ‘default.’

**Step 3: Widget Syntax**

Widgets are included within a section. The syntax to add a widget in a section will be somewhat like this:

```
<b:section id="sidebar" class="sidebar" maxwidgets="" showaddelement="yes">
<b:widget id='CustomSearch1' title='Search' type='CustomSearch' locked='false'/>
<b:widget id='FollowByEmail1' title='Follow By Email' type='FollowByEmail' locked='false' />
<b:widget id='PopularPosts1' locked='false' title='Popular On Relatemein' type='PopularPosts'/>
<b:widget id='Label1' type='Label' locked='false' />
</b:section>
```

From: [Blog TemplateToaster](http://templatetoaster.com/create-blogger-template-tutorial-guide/)

---

### Alternatives

1. Use software that manages the correct code structure for you. I know
   these two: [TemplateToaster](https://templatetoaster.com/) and [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com/).
2. Use a template as a basis for the layout you want to
   create. I usually do it this way because it saves a lot of time and
   I just need to work on the visual part and make minor structural
   changes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Couldn you also tell me how can I add more pages in this layout?

Comment: After adding, copy the page url and add a conditional for that page within the code of your template. `<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + "p/example.html"'> <!-- a specific static page with name 'example' --> </b:if>` All the code inserted within this conditional will only affect the indicated page. [Blogger Conditional](https://ultimatebloggerguide.blogspot.com/2016/07/blogger-conditional-tags-for-page-types.html)